# How to conditionally group multiple columns from a database with linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

The keyword here is "conditionally".

I have the following DataTable:

```
Date   Type              Method   Amount   SerialNumber   TransId  Info
1/1/11 Misc              Check    50.00    5412           1000     NA
1/1/11 Misc              Check    25.00    5413           1001     ABC
1/2/11 Pymt              Fee      15.00    5476           1002     CD
1/3/11 Returned Premium  Transfer 20.00    6741           1105     D
1/3/11 Returned Premium  Transfer 35.00    7456           1106     S
```

**The criteria says the following:**
For payments of type Returned Premium and Method of Transfer on the same date, display one record with the summation of the amount. The type, method, TransId, and serial number should display from the first payment, and Info column should be left blank.

**Here's the output I need:**

```
Date   Type              Method   Amount   SerialNumber   TransId  Info
1/1/11 Misc              Check    50.00    5412           1000     NA
1/1/11 Misc              Check    25.00    5413           1001     ABC
1/2/11 Pymt              Fee      15.00    5476           1002     CD
1/3/11 Returned Premium  Transfer 55.00    6741           1105
```

I tried the below linq, but that would group ALL payments if they have the same Date, Type, and Method. I only need to group those records that have the same Date, Type = Return Premium, and Method = Transfer.

```
var dt = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(row => new
                        {
                            Date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                            TranType = row.Field<string>("Type"),
                            TranMethod = row.Field<string>("Method")
                        }).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).FirstOrDefault();
```

The input is a DataTable, and the output needs to be a DataTable, that's why I'm copyingToDataTable.

Comment: What should happen if you have a single "Returned Premium", "Transfer" on a particular date?

Comment: All records should be treated as individual records except for when the type = Returned Premium, method = Transfer, and these two records have the same Date.

Comment: Why don't you split the data set into two based on the condition, then just group the items that have the condition, and then put the results in a single data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making modifications to the table, LINQ is for querying data. You can use LINQ to search for what needs to be updated then make the modifications, but they have to be done separately.

Search for what items need to be grouped and group them by creating new rows to replace them.

```
var query =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    let date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
    let type = row.Field<string>("Type")
    let method = row.Field<string>("Method")
    let transId = row.Field<int>("TransId")
    where type == "Returned Premium"
    where method == "Transfer"
    orderby date, transId // assuming transactions are ordered by TransId
    group row by date;
foreach (var g in query)
{
    var newRow = table.Rows.Add(g.First().ItemArray);
    newRow.SetField("Amount", g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Amount")));
    foreach (var r in g)
        r.Delete();
}
```